# How to optimise deployment of repository to production server Hippo CMS?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, hippocms

Problems:
Deployment took too long
Namespaces, configurations and contents missing in production server

What I've done:
Followed the guide to deploy my Hippo CMS project [here](http://www.onehippo.org/library/deployment/create-and-deploy-a-project-distribution.html).

What I've found:
When I extract the distribution file, I've found cms.war which includes a huge bootstrap content jar (140MB; myproject-bootstrap-content-2.01.08-SNAPSHOT).
I have a feeling that in my production server, Hippo will try to expand this jar file and write to my production MySQL server.
(That sounds a bit scary to me.)
Am I correct?

It makes the distribution file very big, right now it's 160MB we haven't even launched out site which has relatively little contents yet.
Can we configure Hippo to not include the bootstrap jar and simply connect to the MySQL database assigned?
The contents can be filled up manually.
Data entry is supposed to be a separate matter right?

Answer (score 1):

you can exclude bootstrap jar by creating another profile which includes your content dependency. 
Just edit cms/pom.xml and add following:

```
  <profiles>
<profile>
  <id>local</id>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.YOURGROUP</groupId>
      <artifactId>YOURPROJECT_ARTIFACT-bootstrap-content</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</profile>
```

now you can activate this by using `mvn package -Plocal`
By default it will not be included in distribution package (unless you add -Plocal of course)